# Dynamic coloring output to console in java or python

Tags: java, python, number-theory

I'm working on a project where I print out numbers up to some limit. I want to distinguish all of the even numbers that are expressed as the sum of 3 and another prime number, then I want to distinguish all of the numbers that are expressed as the sum of 5 and another prime number and so on so forth. To distinguish these things from each other I was thinking of outputting to the console in different colors for each prime. I need to be able to increment the color in a dynamic way so that I'm not writing a specific statement and color for every prime number. Anybody know how I can arrange this? Or equivalently, anyone know a good way of printing out distinguishable items?

Comment: Show your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ansi escape sequences for colors](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#colors) in your strings:

```
Black: \u001b[30m
Red: \u001b[31m
Green: \u001b[32m
Yellow: \u001b[33m
Blue: \u001b[34m
Magenta: \u001b[35m
Cyan: \u001b[36m
White: \u001b[37m
Reset: \u001b[0m
```

Inserting any one of the color escape sequences will make all subsequent non-whitespace characters appear in that color until the Reset escape sequence is reached.

If you want to avoid the overhead of concatenating these escape sequences yourself, you can use a library like [Termcolor for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) or [Jansi for Java](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)

Note that generally ANSI escape sequences will not work with Windows (producing garbage instead), although Jansi makes it Windows compatible by either using platform-specific APIs or removing the escape sequences altogether, as appropriate.

Comment: But is there a way to do it dynamically? Can you increment the xxm through a loop? Is there a way to choose each color using rbg amounts?

Comment: Put the color strings in an array and use the next one when necessary. You *will* run into a hardcoded limit somewhere. The possible colors is a limited list – the basic ANSI color set defines only 8 or 16 colors, of which you can't use a few for text (at the very least the background color), and even with an extended console that can handle 24-bit color, you'll run out of colors before you run out of prime numbers.